# Stop Firebug from consolidating css attributes

Tags: firebug

Using Firebug 1.5.4. When I am inspecting an element, Firebug converts declaration "padding: 10px 0 13px 0" to "padding: 10px 0 13px" in the inspection window, which bugs me. Yet it leaves "margin: 0 0 0 16px;" as is which I like. (How come it didn't consolidate that one?)

Is there a setting in Firebug to show all css attributes in expanded (none consolidated) format?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily verify that Firebug is not consolidating as you think it is. Just edit an elements Style using Firebug > HTML > Style > New Property  and use

```
padding: 2px 3px 4px 0;
```

You will see that Firebug does not remove the trailing 0;

My guess is that Firefox chooses not to report a zero value for the trailing values in a shorthand property.  Firebug is just showing you the result.

Comment: I too see, and am annoyed by this, all the time.

Comment: This isn't a display formatting issue as far as I can tell. Firebug is simply reporting what Firefox has to say about the padding.

Comment: Whether Firefox reports or not, Firebug is in control of everything it displays. Firebug can add the 0 if Firefox is not reporting it.

Answer (score 0):

This annoys me too!   Worse, it does it semi-randomly.

For example, `2px 3px 4px 0` doesn't seem to get clipped but `10px 0 13px 0` usually does.

I haven't found any kind of setting, but one work-around is to always specify units.

`10px 0 13px 0px` gets rewritten to `10px 0 13px 0`, which is acceptable.

.

Another workaround is to check the `Expand Shorthand Properties` menu item.  But, this breaks "padding" into "padding-left",  "padding-top", etc.